# need tips and guides on resizing issues

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

When my form is on a small scale screen-size, it appears correctly, but when I increase the width, it does not appear right. Any ideas? Is it normal or is there a way to make it position nicely? This is my fiddle:

jsfiddle.net/aX86d/

I would appreciate if someone can provide me a tutorial on a noob-friendly guide to maintaining the look of the whole web with either a small/wide browser usage as I'm creating for app purposes so different screen resolution usage will surely occur.

Comment: [How to ask a good question on SO.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). [How to ask a good question related to jQuery Mobile.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery-mobile/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your problem is that the height increases when the width of the screen increases, this is because, your blocks (blockA and blockB) and the #user element have percentage widths.  So, when the width increases, due to the width of the screen increasing, the height if the elements also increase, causing this issue.  A good solution for this would be to specify a max-height in the CSS, for example:

```
max-height: 30px;
```

Change the `30px` to the largest you want the element to get, and then try it.  The element will not resize past the max-height.

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aX86d/3/

### EDIT:

Since your problem is horizontal spacing, I would recommend using absolute positioning.  Whenever you position an element absolute, it's parent must be positioned relative.  Then I set top and bottom to 0 and margin to auto 8px, for auto top-bottom, and 8ps left-right.  This centers the element vertically.  See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aX86d/5/).

I should mention that the CSS `calc()` function does not work in some older browsers, but it works in all the current popular browsers.

### Info about absolute positioning:

See [`this page`](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/) on Absolute positioning inside relative positioning.

Basically, this page says that if an absolute position element is inside a relative position element, it's top, bottom, left, and right styles will be relative to the parent.  Otherwise, it will be relative the `body`, instead of it's parent.  Look at the image on the page mentioned, they might help you understand a little better.

Comment: actually it's not about the height, it's about
1) the gaps between the inline elements increases due to screen size becoming wider

2) when the screen gets too small, the element on the right(the form input) will go under the image causing the design to look weird.. Can you help me out?

Comment: Sure, I will update.  Check it again in a few minutes

Comment: are you able to go more detail on the absolute and relative thing because i still find it confusing.. but your is what i need =)

Comment: @MapleseaPowerleveling - I added info about the positioning.  Hope it helps!